# GTK+ pass combo box text to variable

Tags: c, gtk

I'm currently writing a program using GTK+ 2.x, and I have a combo box with some options for it. I'd like, when I press a button to pass that selected option to a variable. Here's what I have for my function:

```
static void selectgame(GtkComboBox *gamelist, gpointer data){
   gchar *game = gtk_combo_box_get_active_text(gamelist);
   g_print( "Selected (simple): >> %s <<\n", ( game ? game : "NULL" ) );
   g_free(game);
}
```

But the error I get from the print function is the following:

```
(Senorita.exe:2228): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_combo_box_get_active_text: assertion `
GTK_IS_COMBO_BOX (combo_box)' failed
```

If I set the g_signal_connect to call the function when the combo box is changed, it works. But when the button is pressed, it doesn't. This is my code for calling the button press:

```
  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(downloadbutton), "clicked",
                         G_CALLBACK(selectgame), NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the active text of a GtkButton. The way this is happening is that the first parameter of your selectgame (or any other callback) is the widget that fired the event. So you want this:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(downloadbutton), "clicked",
                       G_CALLBACK(selectgame), gamelist);
```

where gamelist is your combo box

And

```
static void selectgame(GtkWidget *downloadbutton, GtkComboBox gamelist){
   gchar *game = gtk_combo_box_get_active_text(gamelist);
   g_print( "Selected (simple): >> %s <<\n", ( game ? game : "NULL" ) );
   g_free(game);
}
```

And you should be good to go!

The reason for this is the last parameter of `g_signal_connect` is the second parameter of your callback.

See also: [g_signal_connect documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect)

Comment: Hmm, no, this time I got:

    (Senorita.exe:3724): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid cast from `GtkButton' to `
GtkComboBox'

    (Senorita.exe:3724): Gtk-CRITICAL **:     gtk_combo_box_get_active_text:     assertion `
    GTK_IS_COMBO_BOX (combo_box)' failed
    Selected (simple): >> NULL <<

Comment: @abtekk so gamelist is a button? And you're trying to get the active text of a combo box which is actually a button?

Comment: No, gamelist is the combobox. Downloadbutton is the button that calls the function.